# uncompress ArchiveInputStream in memory

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-compress

Is it possible that if an ArchiveEntry coming from an ArchiveInputStream in the apache commons compress lib is another Archive, that I could then uncompress that archiveEntry into memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. APIs that work with streams will work with `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

If you show a code sample of what you're doing now, I will give you a more specific answer, but the idea is to   read the uncompressed data into a byte array, then create a `ByteArrayInputStream` from it and feed it to the second `ArchiveInputStream`.

Comment: Can you provide an example? ArchiveEntry doesnt seem to have any way to get a stream. The ArchiveEntry itself comes from an ArchiveInputStream in my case but I would like to convert the ArchiveEntry into an in-memory file to pass it back to my function that needs to read it

Comment: Also, it seems like the createArchiveOutputStream from the factory requires that you name the type of the archive. How do I get the type of the ArchiveEntry?